# Is there any plugins of VSCode for angular1.x to "go-to-definition"?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I used to code using webstorm. and it could go to definition simply by pressing `ctrl` and click the dropdown options. 
angular2+ using typescript and supported by VSCode itself already.

anyone's help are appreciated

Comment: hope this question gets the attention it deserves

Comment: At least this functionality exists for pure Ecmascript. Why wouldn't it work for Angular?